# Where to store the App icon in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, macos, ios-icons

I do not use XCode (but Delphi), and I want to know how to set in my app (iOS/macOS) the icons (the icons used to represent my app)? I especially mean inside the `Myapp.app` directory where I need to store the App icon? do I also need to list them in some info.plist (or other similar files?)

Answer (score 1):

**iOS:**

The image files used to represent icons and launch images must all reside in the **root** level of your bundle. How you identify these images to the system can vary, but the recommended way to specify your application icons is to use the `CFBundleIconFiles` key. (`CFBundlePrimaryIcon`)

```
MyApp.app/
   Info.plist
   MyApp
   Default.png
   Icon.png
```

**macOS:**

Icon has to be within **Resources** folder

```
MyApp.app/
   Contents/
      Info.plist
      MacOS/
         MyApp
      Resources/
         Hand.tiff
         MyApp.icns
```

More info:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7

Comment: "Icon has to be within Resources folder" What you are saying is pretty much pointless since any file inside an Xcode project goes to the Resources folder anyway. Or tell us of any mistake that one could make so that a file would end up in the MacOS or other folders.

Comment: Oops...  I'm sorry about that.